# How do i push user input onto my queue?

Tags: c++, queue

I can't figure out how to get user input, and push it onto my queue. I tried finding examples but couldn't find anything. Here is a piece of my code:

```
queue<int> temp;

int Temperature::getTemp()
{
//excluded code
getline(myEngFile1, tempLine1); // assigns "what is temp?" to tempLine1
cout<<tempLine1<<"\n"; // What is the Temperature?
//cin>>value;
temp.push(value);
return value;
myEngFile1.close();
}
```

How do i get it so that i can read the user's input and push it onto my queue?

Comment: What is wrong with this example? How is it not working?

Comment: Move that `myEngFile1.close();` before `return` nothing will be executed.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It didnt work because i commented out the "Cin>>value" cause im an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
 int i;
 cout << "Enter a value to put in queue:";
 cin >> i;
 temp.push(i);
```

To enter more than one value, you can wrap it inside a loop until the user enters some invalid value.

```
bool ok = true;
while(ok) {
  //get input like above
  //check if "i" is still ok
  //if ok the push on queue
  //else set ok to false
}
```

Comment: Oh so I was right then lol i just have to uncomment that line...I though that for whatever reason by doing that, it doesnt actually push it on.

Comment: `cin >> i` is the line that reads input from the user into the variable `i`. The line below it pushes the value of `i` onto your stack.